# setsockopt does not work, but does not return errno

Tags: c, windows, sockets, error-handling

My code is intended to establish a simple connection between two computers using a socket (the winsock2.h one), but the setsockopt phase does not work (returns a negative value) without a valid errno (a null errno unless I initialize the variable beforehand).

Here is my minified code:

```
// I include winsock2.h, errno.h and other needed (and less important) stuff

int optval = 1;
errno = 0;

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0){
    print("TCP socket error, %s", strerr(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

When running, the program outputs:

> TCP socket error, No error

This output, from my point of view, tells me that, either there is no error and the conditional is mistakenly evaluated (perhaps returning under zero does not mean an error), or something strange happens with the errno (as a reminder, if i did not initialize the errno variable it would be null, perhaps winsock2.h does not use it).

Comment: In any case if youi're gpoing to `connect()` this socket rather than `listen()` with it, as implied by your text, there is no point to this. The system will choose you a free local port.

Comment: when working with the microsoft functions, as exposed via `#include <windows.h>` then need to use the exposed function: `getlasterror()`  However, best to use: `#include <errno.h>`  and call `strerror( errno );`

Comment: @user3629249 `errno`  and friends do not operate with Winsock. See the answer by dbush.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne,  I had already marked that answer up.   However, the OP would have been MUCH better off to use the linux headers and functions as `windows.h` is not portable

Comment: @user3629249 Marking it is one thing: understanding it is evidently quite another. The Linux headers are for Linux. The Winsock headers are for Windows. He is using Winsock, *ergo* he is on Windows. And he has expressed no interest in portability. Your comments don't make sense.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, In reality, what I called the `linux` headers are the standard C library headers.

Comment: @user3629249 In reality (1) WIndows compilers do not supply Linux header files; (2) the Linux socket include files are not part of the standard C library; (3) Winsock does not set `errno`; (4) it is clear that you have never compiled a WInsock program.

Comment: the standard C header files (and librarys) are not limited to linux,   Actually, I worked several contracts that only used the microsoft 'special' headers and libraries.  They are non portable and contain several 'gotchas'.  SO I never recommend them

Comment: @user3629249 The Standard C library headers are limited to *less* than what Linux provides, and as of the time of writing don't include anything about sockets whatsoever. Look it up. Try it. Please inform yourself before posting on this topic. I am not guessing about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows sockets functions don't set `errno` when they fail.

You need to instead call `WSAGetLastError` to get the most recent error code and `FormatMessage` message to get the textual equivalent.

```
if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0){
    char errbuf[300];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, WSAGetLastError(),
                  0, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf), NULL);
    printf("TCP socket error: %s", errbuf);
}
```

Comment: Other than errors should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using `fprintf( stderr, "TCP socket error: %s\n", errbuf );`

Comment: It returns an equivalent message. While errno returns *No error*, WSAGetLastError says that *the program has not called WSAStartup, or there is no error*. What if there is no actual error?

Comment: @Vyber90`WSAStartup` needs to be called before any other socket functions to initialize winsock.  If you haven't called this function already you should do so.

Comment: @dbush roger. I thought winsock2.h would have already called it

Comment: @Vyber90 winsock2.h is just a header file containing function declarations.  It doesn't call anything.  Unlike the socket libraries in Linux, Windows makes you call an extra function for initialization.